# Laravel OpenShift Deployment Issue in database migrations

Tags: laravel-4, openshift, openshift-php-cartidges

I am trying to deploy a Laravel 4.2 application on RedHat OpenShift.
I have successfully transferred the code from GitHub but I am stuck at the database integration.

How do I run the migrations?

- I have created a new `mysql_openshift` database connection with
  OpenShift credentials and updated the same.
- I have a migration file in the migrations folder.
- But on running the `php artisan migrate` i get the following error:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQbam.png

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

The [Laravel 4.2 QuickStart](https://hub.openshift.com/quickstarts/124-laravel-4-2) was updated 2 days ago. The QuickStart now automatically runs `php artisan migrate` when you deploy changes to OpenShift. I definitely recommend switching over to using the QuickStart or updating to the latest version.

Anyways, the short answer to the problem you're seeing: your database is not configured properly in Laravel. See [lines 60-70 of `app/config/database.php`](https://github.com/luciddreamz/laravel-4.2/blob/master/app/config/database.php#L60) in the Laravel 4.2 QuickStart for a reference on configuring the host/port connection info.

Answer (score 0):

Your openshift db parameters are not set correctly.

Look at your config/database.php you will see how the setting in .env are used. Like before we try to get environmental variables from Openshift. The function env('DB_HOST', 'default') will take either DB_HOST from .env or use the default value in the second parameter. Since .env is excluded from version control, Laravel will take the Openshift-specific settings instead.

So put the following code in your config/app.php :

```
'mysql' => [
'driver'    => 'mysql',
'host'      => env('DB_HOST', getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST')),
'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', getenv('OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME')),
'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_USERNAME')),
'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD')),
'port'      => env('DB_PORT', getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT')),
'charset'   => 'utf8',
'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
'prefix'    => '',
'strict'    => false,],
```